# Fetch data from dynamodb table based upon user role/access

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have created a single table DB Model for my project. It contains multiple products. The application has 3 user roles SuperUser, ProductOwner & BasicUser. I want to fetch multiple products to show in a table in UI where logged-in user should see only those products on which user is having access. e.g. SuperUser can see all the products whereas a ProductOwner can see only those products on which he is ProductOwner. How can I achieve this behavior in dynamodb model

Answer (score 0):

You can put another attribute in dynamodb which basically stores the users/role names to whom the product is accessible. As you are saying for superuser everything is accessible, so for SuperUser you can directly return all the products but for the other two roles you can use this technique

Comment: yeah, that is one of the options I have identified but for that I need to apply filter while fetching data and in case there are millions of records then filter will be costly.